# End a function when one of the conditions is true using the Map method

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JS and am trying to write a function that returns true whenever a string has a letter 'b' exactly 3 characters away from any letter 'a', and false if not. For example:

"lsufa kfba" = true

"lsufakfba" = true

"viajs inabn" = false

I've read that the return statement ends the function but it only adds it to the array index in this case. How can I get it to end the function entirely here? Thanks for any help.

```js
var a = "lsufa kfba";
var b = (a.split(' ').join('')).split('a'); // returns ["lsuf", "kfb", ""];

b.map(function(c, i) {
  if (c[2] == 'b') {
    console.log('value: ' + c[2] + ' is b; true');
    return true;
  } else {
    console.log('false');
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: If you're just trying to omit what doesn't meet your requirement then use `.filter()` instead of `.map()`

Comment: @str that won't meet the position requirement `whenever a string has a letter 'b' 3 characters away from any letter 'a'`

Comment: why is the first `true`, but the third `false`?

Comment: The first one should be false since you have " ", "k", "f" and "b" after "a", i.e. "b" is the fourth character after "a".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the approach I've provided can be simplified using other methods, since you mentioned you are new to JS, I have provided a more long-winded answer which should help you understand what is going on.

In the snippet below I've created a function `checkString()` which accepts a string as an argument, and returns `true` or `false` if the string matches your criteria.

The first part of the function involves looping over the string and getting each character in the string. At each iteration (step in the loop) we check if this character is equal to 'a'. We also store the letter located at the position offset by three in the variable `possibleB` which will hold the letter 3 spots away from the letter 'a'.

We then use an if statement to check if the current letter (`currentLetter`) that we are looking at is 'a' and the letter 3 away from the current letter(`possibleB`) is 'b'. If this is the case, we can return true.

Take a look at the snippet below and the comments to get a better understanding of what is going on:

```js
//whenever a string has a letter 'b' 3 characters away from any letter 'a' return true
function checkString(str) {
  str = str.replace(/\s/g, ''); // remove all spaces from the string (so a ccb = accb which is now true)
  for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if(i+3 > str.length-1) { // If the index+3 is greater than the string length, then there is is no 'b'
      return false;
    }
    
    var currentLetter = str[i];
    var possibleB = str[i+3]
    if(currentLetter == 'a' && possibleB == 'b' || currentLetter == 'b' && possibleB == 'a') { // if the current letter is a and the letter 3 stops away from our current letter is 'b', return true
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false; // If our for loop hasn't quit by returing yet, we know the string doesn't match our test case
}

// Test cases
console.log(checkString("lsufa kfba"));
console.log(checkString("lsufakfba"));
console.log(checkString("lsufa kffa lsufa kfba")); // test multiple spaces
console.log(checkString("viajs inabn"));
console.log(checkString("a ccb"));
console.log(checkString("b cca")); // test b before a
```

Comment: `str.replace(' ', '')` replaces only first space

Comment: very helpful, will note that for next time. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Solution with regex:

```js
const test = ["lsufa kfba", "lsufakfba", "lsufakkkkfba", "lsufbkfaa"];

function foo(str) {
  let trimmed = str.replace(/\s/g, '');
  return /a.{2}b/.test(trimmed) || /b.{2}a/.test(trimmed);
}

test.forEach(a=>console.log(a, foo(a)));
```

It checks whether string after whitespaces removal contains sequence 
 `a`*-2characters-*`b` or `b`*-2characters-*`a`

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `Array.some()`

```js
const a = "lsufa kfba";

function foo(str) {
  let index;
  return str.replace(/\s/g, '').split('').some((l, i) => {
    if (l === 'a') {
      index = i;
    }
    if (l === 'b' && i - 3 === index) return true;
  })
}

console.log(foo(a));
```

Comment: Great approach, but does not cover case where the `b` comes before the `a`.